# Zariski topology on the prime spectrum of a commutative ring: closed sets

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra

Let $S$ be a subset of the ring $R$ and $\text{Spec}(R)$ be the prime spectrum of $R$. Let $V(S)(\subset\text{Spec}(R))$ be the set of all prime ideals of $R$ which contain $S$. My question relates to the Zariski Topology.

It is known that $V(\cup_i S_i)=\cap_i V(S_i)$ and $V(S_i\cap S_j)=V(S_i)\cup V(S_j)$.

What exactly turns the subsets $V(S)$ with $S\subseteq R$ into the set of closed sets in a topology on $\text{Spec}(R)$? How do you argue?

Comment: first of all, what you've written about $V(S\cap T)$ is not correct if you're looking at arbitrary subsets. indeed consider for example the case $R=\mathbb{Z}$, and let $S=\{1\}$ and $T=\{-1\}$. then $V(S)=V(T)=\varnothing$, but $V(S\cap T)=V(\varnothing)=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$.  you do not want to define $V(S)$ for arbitrary subsets $S\subseteq R$; instead you only want to define it when $S$ is an *ideal*.

Comment: second of all, are you just asking why declaring the closed subsets to be precisely the $V(I)$ for $I$ an ideal indeed gives you a topology? for that you've already essentially shown why in your post. by the equations you write (which do hold if the $S_i$ are ideals), this family of sets is closed under arbitrary intersections and finite unions. so to show they indeed yield a topology you need only show that $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ and $\varnothing$ can be written in the form $V(I)$ for some $I$, and then you're done. can you see how to do this?

Comment: This makes sense now. I should have specified that I meant finite set operations.